# How is the standard DelegateCommand CanExecuteChanged event fired in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, delegatecommand

I want to re-trigger the canExecute functionality from a DelegateCommand after some modifications have been made by the user. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The event CanExecuteChanged of the interface ICommand must be raised to re-trigger call of the CanExecute method.

Create a public method "RaiseCanExecuteChanged" in the DelegateCommand which fires the event.